# How to get a fileEntry to then use readAsText in cordova / ionic(2)?

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2

In my Ionic2 app I managed to successfully use certain methods of the File plugin such as:

- checkDir
- createDir
- createFile

Now I want to use **readAsText** (as specified [in the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/)) but I can't figure out **how to get a fileEntry without creating a new file, (which apparently would require overriding it**)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a fileEntry by using [cordova-plugin-filepath](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/)

If you have an URI starting with *"content://*", we need the local file URI starting with *"file://"*.

*FilePath.resolveNativePath* returns the local file url.

```
let uri = "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary/data...";

window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri, (localFileUri) => {
   // result is file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/...
   // now get a fileEntry from this uri
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(localFileUri, (fileEntry) => {

   });
});
```

File Entry, has a method "file" which can be used to get a file object and read the content of the file with FileReader, e.g:

```
fileEntry.file((file) => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = (e) => {
       let result =  e.target.result; // text content of the file
       // do whatever you like 
    };
reader.readAsText(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using the `readAsText()` function if you know the path of the file:

```
const fs:string = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;

File.readAsText(fs, filePath).then((contents) => {
    if(typeof contents == 'string'){
        processFile(contents);
    }
});
```

One slight *gotcha* is that the file path must not start with a `/`.

An example where this might catch you is when processing files in a directory;

```
const fs:string = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;

File.listDir(fs, "").then(files => {      
    for (let file of files){
        if(file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")){  
            File.readAsText(fs, file.fullPath.substr(1)).then((contents) => {
                if(typeof contents == 'string'){
                    processFile(contents);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```